# tab on component visibility based on profile

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I want to use the same page layout for multiple profiles. There is 1 profile where I would like to show an additional tab, so tab 1 = details, tab 2 is only visible if profile = "x"

is there anyway to accomplish this?. tab 1 is details, tab 2 consists of a lightning component.

inside page layout editor,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBhtf.jpg

Comment: Were you able to get some poc component or start development absed on my below answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this functionality by creating a custom lightning component.

You might want to look into the [lightning:tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm) component, when you initialize your component, you will want to check the current users profile in your Apex class using the [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) Class to determine the Profile.

Based on the profile, you should be able to control what tabs are create/displayed in your component markup.

If you are unsure on how to proceed, I would suggest you check [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics).